# Convert image data to format needed for gfa

Tags: image, zebra-printers, zpl

If I have an Image file (png, bmp, or jpg), and I need to get the data for the ZPL GFA tag, how do I do that?

I would like some example in vb.net or C#

Answer (score 2):

please add this class to your project:

```
public class zplImageConverter : Component, IBindableComponent
{
    private int blackLimit=125;
    private int total;
    private int widthBytes;
    private bool compressHex= false;

    public int BlacknessLimitPercentage
    {
        get
        {
            return (blackLimit * 100 / 255);
        }
        set
        {
            blackLimit = (value * 255 / 100);
        }
    }

    public bool CompressHex
    {
        get { return compressHex; }
        set { compressHex = value; }
    }

    private Image _image = null;

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            _image = value;
        }
    }

    public string zplValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this._image != null ? FromImage( (Bitmap)this._image ) : "^A0,10,8^FDError!";
        }
    }

    #region IBindableComponent Members
    private BindingContext bindingContext;
    private ControlBindingsCollection dataBindings;
    [Browsable( false )]
    public BindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                bindingContext = new BindingContext();
            }
            return bindingContext;
        }
        set
        {
            bindingContext = value;
        }
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility( DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content )]
    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
    {
        get
        {
            if (dataBindings == null)
            {
                dataBindings = new ControlBindingsCollection( this );
            }
            return dataBindings;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private static Dictionary<int, string> mapCode= new Dictionary<int, string>() {
        { 1,"G"},
        { 2,"H"},
        { 3,"I"},
        { 4,"J"},
        { 5,"K"},
        { 6,"L"},
        { 7,"M"},
        { 8,"N"},
        { 9,"O"},
        { 10, "P"},
        { 11, "Q"},
        { 12, "R"},
        { 13, "S"},
        { 14, "T"},
        { 15, "U"},
        { 16, "V"},
        { 17, "W"},
        { 18, "X"},
        { 19, "Y"},
        { 20, "g"},
        { 40, "h"},
        { 60, "i"},
        { 80, "j"},
        { 100, "k"},
        { 120, "l"},
        { 140, "m"},
        { 160, "n"},
        { 180, "o"},
        { 200, "p"},
        { 220, "q"},
        { 240, "r"},
        { 260, "s"},
        { 280, "t"},
        { 300, "u"},
        { 320, "v"},
        { 340, "w"},
        { 360, "x"},
        { 380, "y"},
        { 400, "z"},
    };
    public string FromImage( Bitmap image )
    {
        string cuerpo= createBody(image);
        if (compressHex) cuerpo = HexToAscii( cuerpo );
        return headDoc() + cuerpo;
    }
    private string createBody( Bitmap orginalImage )
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage( orginalImage);
        graphics.DrawImage( orginalImage, 0, 0 );

        int height = orginalImage.Height;
        int width = orginalImage.Width;
        int index = 0;
        // int rgb;
        int red;
        int green;
        int blue;
        char[] auxBinaryChar = new char[] { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };

        widthBytes = (width / 8);

        if (((width % 8)
                    > 0))
        {
            widthBytes = (((int)((width / 8))) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            widthBytes = (width / 8);
        }

        this.total = (widthBytes * height);
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < width ; w++)
            {
                var  rgb = orginalImage.GetPixel( w, h );
                red = rgb.R;
                green = rgb.G;
                blue = rgb.B;

                char auxChar = '1';


                int totalColor = (red + green + blue)/3;


                if ((totalColor > blackLimit || rgb.A<= blackLimit)) auxChar = '0';


                auxBinaryChar[index] = auxChar;
                index++;

                if (((index == 8) || (w == (width - 1))))
                {
                    sb.Append( ByteBinary( new string( auxBinaryChar ) ) );

                    auxBinaryChar = new char[] { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };
                    index = 0;
                }                    
            }

            sb.Append( "\n" );
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private string ByteBinary( string binary )
    {
        int dec = Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2);//int.Parse(binaryStr);//Integer.parseInt(binaryStr,2);
        if (dec > 15)
        {
            return dec.ToString( "X" ).ToUpper();//int.toString( dec, 16 ).toUpperCase();
        }
        else
        {
            return "0" + dec.ToString( "X" ).ToUpper();//Integer.toString( dec, 16 ).toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    private string HexToAscii( string code )
    {
        int maxlinea =  widthBytes * 2;

        StringBuilder sbCode = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbLinea = new StringBuilder();
        String previousLine = null;
        int counter = 1;

        char aux = code[0];

        bool firstChar = false;

        for (int i = 1; i < code.Length; i++)
        {
            var d=code[i];

            if (firstChar)
            {
                aux = code[i];
                firstChar = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (code[i] == '\n')
            {
                if (counter >= maxlinea && aux == '0')
                {
                    sbLinea.Append( "," );
                }
                else if (counter >= maxlinea && aux == 'F')
                {
                    sbLinea.Append( "!" );
                }
                else if (counter > 20)
                {
                    int multi20 = (counter/20)*20;
                    int resto20 = (counter%20);

                    sbLinea.Append( mapCode[multi20] );

                    if (resto20 != 0)
                    {
                        sbLinea.Append( mapCode[resto20] + aux );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbLinea.Append( aux );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sbLinea.Append( mapCode[counter] + aux );
                    if (mapCode[counter] == null) { }
                }
                counter = 1;
                firstChar = true;
                if (sbLinea.ToString().Equals( previousLine ))
                {
                    sbCode.Append( ":" );
                }
                else
                {
                    sbCode.Append( sbLinea.ToString() );
                }
                previousLine = sbLinea.ToString();
                sbLinea.Clear();//.setLength( 0 );
                continue;
            }
            if (aux == code[i])
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (counter > 20)
                {
                    int multi20 = (counter/20)*20;
                    int resto20 = (counter%20);
                    sbLinea.Append( mapCode[multi20] );
                    if (resto20 != 0)
                    {
                        sbLinea.Append( mapCode[resto20] + aux );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbLinea.Append( aux );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sbLinea.Append( mapCode[counter] + aux );
                }
                counter = 1;
                aux = code[i];
            }
        }
        return sbCode.ToString();
    }
    private String headDoc()
    {
        String str = "^GFA,"+ total + ","+ total + "," + widthBytes +", \n";
        return str;
    }
}
```

then to use:

```
        zplImageConverter cvt= new  zplImageConverter();

        cvt.Image = Properties.Resources.images;//Set Image to convert
        cvt.CompressHex = true;// Enable compresion HexString
        cvt.BlacknessLimitPercentage = 50;// Configure the porcentaje for ilumination

        Console.WriteLine( cvt.zplValue );// Print on Screen the zplCode (add ^XA before and ^XZ after and try on http://labelary.com/viewer.html)
```

[labelary.com](http://labelary.com/viewer.html)

Comment: A bit of explanations would be great.